# Aggregate List<X> to List<X> with Java 8 Stream API

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I've got the following class:

```
class Money {
  CurrencyUnit currencyUnit;
  BigDecimal amount;
}
```

In my application, I get some random list of `Money` objects:

```
currencyUnit | amount
---------------------
EUR          | 5.1
EUR          | 0
USD          | 1.09
EUR          | 42
USD          | 3
```

Now I'd like to use the Java 8 Stream API to create the following result (simply calling `BigDecimal::add` for each currencyUnit's amount):

```
currencyUnit | amount
---------------------
EUR          | 47.1
USD          | 4.09
```

What I already know/did:

```
Stream<Money> moneyStream = moneyList.stream();
```

And here it ends already. I know I can use a `Collector` to produce a `Map<CurrencyUnit, List<Money>>`:

```
moneyStream.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(m -> m.getCurrencyUnit());
```

But then I still have to go through all key-value-pairs and sum up the amount data.

What's the right (and possibly easiest way) to do that? It can't be that complicated, right? `:)`

---

EDIT: If it's not that clear what I need, here's my old-way Java code:

```
Map<CurrencyUnit, Money> map = new HashMap<>();
moneyList.stream().forEach(e -> {
    Money m = map.get(e.getCurrencyUnit());
    if(m == null) {
        m = new Money();
        m.setAmount(BigDecimal.ZERO);
        m.setCurrencyUnit(e.getCurrencyUnit());
        map.put(e.getCurrencyUnit(), m);
    }
    m.setAmount(m.getAmount().add(e.getAmount()));
});
return map.values();
```

---

EDIT 2: Another solution, which isn't really elegant:

```
List<Money> list = inputList.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Money::getCurrencyUnit))
    .values().stream().map(ml -> {
        Money money = new Money();
        ml.forEach(m -> {
            if(money.getCurrencyUnit() == null) {
                money.setCurrencyUnit(m.getCurrencyUnit());
                money.setAmount(m.getAmount());
            } else {
                money.setAmount(money.getAmount().add(m.getAmount()));
            }
        });
        return money;
    }).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use a `groupingBy` collector to group the objects by `CurrencyUnit`. Without second argument, the `groupingBy` method collects the elements into a list. However, you can also specify a *downstream collector*  if you need something else.

You can use `Collectors::summingInt` and `Collectors::summingLong` for `int` and `long`. For `BigDecimal`, you can fall back to `Collectors::reducing`:

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.groupingBy;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.reducing;

Map<CurrencyUnit, BigDecimal> result = moneyList.stream()
    .collect(
        groupingBy(
            Money::getCurrencyUnit,
            reducing(BigDecimal.ZERO, Money::getAmount, BigDecimal::add)));
```

---

**Edit:** You can also create `List<Money>`:

```
List<Money> result = moneyList.stream()
    .collect(
        groupingBy(
            Money::getCurrencyUnit,
            reducing(BigDecimal.ZERO, Money::getAmount, BigDecimal::add)))
    .entrySet().stream()
    .map(e -> new Money(e.getKey(), e.getValue())
    .collect(toList());
```

Comment: Thank you. That's close to what I need, but your code gives me a `Map`. Isn't it possible to get back a `List` or a `Set`? (without manually creating new `Money` objects, etc.)

Comment: Just 5 minutes ago, the idea with iterating over the entrySet came to my mind, but I thought: That's really ugly, there must be something more sexy / elegant. `---` But I think your given answer is the only way of doing it. `---` just right now I thought about: `moneyStream.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(m -> m.getCurrencyUnit());` and then use the generated `Map<CurrencyUnit, List<Money>>` with `map.values().stream()` to produce a `List<Money>` ?!